# How to query multiple words from single string in MONGODB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of requests. One of its field is "content" which is string. Suppose it is "Hello, how's you". How should I query by providing two words "hello" and "you"?

Comment: Why not just write two queries and combine them using `$and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mongo Text Search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) as following:

First create index on key that you want to search like

```
db.collection.createIndex({ content: "text"});
```

and then search like -

```
db.collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "Hello, you"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) as below :

```
db.collectionName.find({"content":{"$regex":"hello$|you$"}})
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this as it would always require a table scan.